# Python API: How to join the table rearranged by the pivot by statement with other tables?

Tags: join, merge, dolphindb

I use Python API and the following is my script:

```
factors = s.table("dfs://K_FACTOR_LONG", "factor_k_long")
kline = s.table("dfs://daily", "quotes")

t1 = trade.select("value").where("tradetime between timestamp(2023.11.06):timestamp(2023.11.11)").pivotby("tradetime", "securityid,factorname")
m = t1.merge(kline, left_on=["securityid", "time_key"], right_on=["securityid", "tradetime"], how="left")
```

“factors” is a narrow table containing 101 alphas. “kline“ contains the data of the original 1-minute OHLC bars. I want to join these two tables but an error occurs: `File "ddb_read.py", line 29, in <module> m = t1.merge(kline, left_on=["securityid", "time_key"], right_on=["securityid", "tradetime"], how="left") AttributeError: 'TablePivotBy' object has no attribute 'merge'`.

How to directly join them in DolphinDB, instead of using the toDF method to download table objects to Python and convert them to a DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

The result of the `pivot by` statement cannot be directly joined with other tables. To achieve this, you can convert the result to a DolphinDB table using the `executeAs` method before joining. You can also call `s.run` to execute SQL statements for the join operation. Either way, all calculations are carried out in DolphinDB and the results are passed to Python through the DolphinDB Python API.